# Showing compactness of subset of $\mathbb{R}^S$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

I want to show compactness of the following subset:

For a countable dense subset $S = (s_1,s_2,...)\subset \mathbb{R}_+$ consider $\mathbb{R}^S$ as the space of functions $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as a topological space using the topology of pointwise convergence. Furthermore let $x_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $E$ be the set of all $f\in \mathbb{R}^S$ such that $\vert f(s_n)\vert \leq x_n$. Why is $E$ compact?

Comment: This is the countable case of [Tychonoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem).

Comment: could you please be so kind to say some more words to that?

Comment: especially I do not see the product here

Comment: $E=\prod\limits_{k\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}}[-x_k,x_k]$, both as a set and as a topological spaces, since you are using the "topology of pointwise convergence" (wich is typically a shorthand name for the product topology).